# Orientation Change Saves Draft and Prompts to Discard/Resume

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

If I change the screen orientation while creating a question, the alert dialog is displayed stating that a draft has been saved. It prompts me to "Resume" our "Discard" the question. This happens on both vertical and horizontal orientation changes.

I'm on version 0.1.38

**Update**

If I don't enter any text it doesn't happen. If I have started typing anything and change orientation, that is when it prompts me.

Also, every time the screen is turned off and back on while an alert dialog is displayed, a new one is created. Doesn't seem to be a limit on how many can be created as long as you don't close any before turning the screen on and off. Thanks to HodofHod for catching this.

I'm using v0.1.39 now and same result.

Comment: Double bonus: Turn the screen off and on. Now you have two prompts.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Nice catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. As of version 0.1.40 coming out later tonight, both of these issues will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it again after the update and mark this as answer.