# Orientation Change Causes Resume/Discard Prompt when Creating a Question in Android App

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I created a post about this same issue a couple months ago but it appears to have resurrected. The issue is when you are creating a question in the Android app, if you change the screen orientation, it prompts you to `Discard` or `Resume`. It happens on both horizontal and vertical orientation changes.

In my other post, I stated that if I hadn't entered any text yet it doesn't happen but this time that doesn't seem to be the case. The first time I changed the orientation without entering any text it did not prompt me but that was the only time. I closed the app then tried again without entering any text and it did prompt me, as did it on a third and forth try. After I have already started a question and change the orientation, it seems to happen every time.

The other post also stated that turning the screen on and off while the error was showing caused a second prompt. I tried this but was not able to duplicate it using those steps.

Reference to the post I've mentioned: [Orientation Change Saves Draft and Prompts to Discard/Resume](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197720/222390)

I'm on version 0.1.70

Comment: I'm assuming this is a new bug with similar symptoms so posting a new question seems fair enough

Comment: @RichardTingle yes, it was originally fixed but seems to have popped back up. I just wasn't sure though and didn't want to accidentally use the site wrong. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The correct procedure when a bug reoccurs is to post a new report, so you're good.

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks for the confirmation, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now finally fixed for good. My fix for it last time was just a bandaid since I put logic for not showing it in the actual ask interface, where as the rotation was actually creating a ripple effect starting at the parent of that view.

This will be in the update (0.1.85) coming out tonight around midnight UTC.

Comment: Thank you sir! I'll mark it answered soon as I get the update!